# The Sitecore Management Service version of the environment this Sitecore CLI operates with is outdated/Sitecore Headless

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, headless-cms

I'm using Sitecore Headless ASP.NET Core Getting Started Template to build my project. Everything works fine until I use Sitecore CLI (`dotnet sitecore ser pull`) and get this error:

> The Sitecore Management Service version of the environment this Sitecore CLI operates with is outdated, please update the Sitecore Management Service to version 5.1.25.

I checked my CLI version. It's already at version 5.1.25. Can anyone help me with this error?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This error message says that your CLI version is already 5.1.25 but Sitecore Management Service module is outdated and you should update it to version 5.1.25 too.

You can do it by downloading and installing the relevant Sitecore Management Service package:

1. Download the Sitecore.ManagementServices package file from [the Sitecore Downloads site](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_CLI.aspx).
2. On the Sitecore CM website, go to the Launchpad, click Control Panel → Install a package. Then follow the Installation Wizard to install the `Sitecore.ManagementServices` package file.

This is required because starting with version 5.1.25 the CLI has a [version compatibility feature](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/version-compatibility.html) that prevents you from running CLI commands with an outdated version of Sitecore Management Services.

Answer (score 1):

Try running below commands in powershell,

```
dotnet sitecore plugin add -n Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization
dotnet sitecore plugin add -n Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Publishing
```

Make sure you have installed the Sitecore cli correctly, or follow the instructions here at [doc.sitecore.com](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/install-sitecore-command-line-interface.html)